# Identifying the quotient space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X.$ Let $$V = \left \{f \in C(X)\ \big |\ f(x) = 0,\ \text {for all}\ x \in K \right \}.$$ Then identify the quotient normed linear space $C(X)/V.$

For each $x \in K$ I define linear maps $T_x : C(X) \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ defined by $T_x (f) = f(x), f \in C(X).$ Clearly each $T_x$ is a bounded linear map with $\|T_x\|_{\text {op}} = 1,$ for all $x \in K.$ Hence $\text {Ker} (T_x)$ is a closed subspace of $C(X),$ for all $x \in K.$  So $V = \bigcap\limits_{x \in K} \text {Ker} (T_x)$ is also a closed subspace of $C(X).$ So $C(X)/V$ is a valid normed linear space endowed with the quotient norm. But I can't able think of a known normed linear space to which $C(X)/V$ is isomorphic. I am guessing that this quotient space has something to do with $C_c (X).$ But I am unable to figure out how? Any suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C(X)/V$ can be identified with $C(K)$. If $g \in C(K)$ there is an extension of $g$ to an element $G$ of $C(X)$ preserving the sup norm by Tietze Extension Theorem. If $H$ is another extension then $G-H$ vanishes on $K$ so $G+V=H+V$. Now look at the map $g \to G$. It is easy to check that this is injective. Given any element $f+V$ of $C(X)/V$ check that $f+V$ is the image of $g$ where $g$ is the restriction of $f$ to $K$. You can also verify that $\|G+V\|=\|g\|$ for all $g \in C(K)$.

Comment: I am able to prove that $\|G + V\| \geq \|g\|_{\infty}.$ What I did is as follows $:$ $$\begin{align*} \|G + V\| & = \inf\limits_{f \in V} \|G - f\|_{\infty} \\ & = \inf\limits_{f \in V} \left ( \sup\limits_{x \in X}  |G(x) - f(x)| \right ) \\ & \geq \inf\limits_{f \in V} \left (\sup\limits_{x \in K} |G(x) - f(x)| \right ) \\ & = \sup\limits_{x \in K} |G(x)| \\ & = \sup\limits_{x \in K} |g(x)| = \|g\|_{\infty}. \end{align*}$$ How to prove the reverse inequality?

Comment: @Anacardium The reverse inequality is obvious: $\|G+V|| \leq \|G\|=\|g\|$.

Comment: How do you know that $\|G\|_{\infty} = \|g\|_{\infty}\ $? Is it happening due to Tietze's extension theorem?

Comment: Yes, It follows by  Tietze Theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your kind help.